# Continuously many i.i.d random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

How can we rigorously construct i.i.d random variables $X_r$ (say with a probability measure $P$ on $[0, 1]$) for each $r \in [0, 1]$, so that we can ask, for example, what is the expected measure of $\{r \in [0, 1] \mid X_r \in A\}$, which perhaps should be $P(A)$? Also, can we show that, almost surely, the measure of $\{r \in [0, 1] \mid X_r \in A\}$ is just $P(A)$ for any measurable $A \subseteq [0, 1]$?

Comment: It depends on the pdf of $X_r$. If the distribution function is invertible, then you can construct such random variables from uniformly distributed random variables, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling. For more complex random variables, you may turn to methods like MCMC

Comment: Construction of arbitrary products of probability spaces is discussed in detail in Real and Abstract Analysis by Hewitt and Stromberg.